# I have a MacBook Pro 2016 just updated to Sonoma then it went into Bootkicker.efi Openshell.efi Reset NVRAM I’ve tried everything nothing has worked

Tags: boot, macbook, recovery, mode

My MacBook Pro has the update Sonoma before the update there were absolutely no problems.

But since the update I can’t get it to boot in recovery mode it keeps going to BootKicker.efi.

Then when I do try to put it in recovery mode it doesn’t recognize my internet so I don’t know what else to do.

Comment: You say you cannot get it into recovery mode, and then you say that when you try to get it into recovery mode the internet doesn't work. Could you please clarify the process/steps leading up to the internet not working? Do you mean that after you've booted normally after failing to get into recovery internet doesn't work, or something else?

Comment: Had you updated OpenCore first? I'd guess you're going to have to start over & boot from a USB stick.

Comment: OpenCore, while brilliant, is also a "YMMV" tool, and failures can and should be expected when it is used. It is manipulating system firmware on a system notoriously integrated.